# Android Development - not able to recognise my Samsung s4 mini - unauthorized

Tags: android

Thank you for taking the time to read this

I'm attempting to create an Android app for the first time and I thought it would be best to use my personal mobile rather than the emulator provided in the Development tool.  When I try to connect to my phone to run my build my phone isn't recognised.

I've read a number of forums and I've updated my drivers, installed Kies, accessed the Developer options and put my phone in debugging mode but it's still not being recognised.

The message shows my phone in a State of Unauthorized and Compatible "No, minSdk(API 19)>deviceSdk(API 1).  My phone is Android version 4.4.2, higher than the minimum pack I set when creating the project.

Thanks in advance for any possible solutions

Comment: I'm not certain this is the answer, but have you enabled developer mode in the settings? Open Settings> About> Software Information> More. Then tap “Build number” seven times to enable Developer options. Go back to Settings menu and now you'll be able to see “Developer options” there.
    Tap it and turn on USB Debugging from the menu on the next screen.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but have you allowed (not only enabled) debugging? When your phone is connected to your computer a dialog will pop up and you have to allow debugging first, with an option to always allow for that computer

Comment: You should set the minSdkVersion to 8 (Android 2.2), 9 (Android 2.3) or better 14 (Android 4.0). Lower versions of Android are more or less meaningless.

Comment: Did you unlock the phone and accept the ADB host in a dialog that pops up?  If you don't see one, go into settings and clear the USB debug authorizations, plug cycle the phone, and try again.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? Windows or Mac?  What JDK and JRE versions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

daxter1992 - I'm really embarrassed to admit it but I'd enabled my phone before I connected it to my laptop.  When I did connect it, I never had the option to allow debugging.  I've since enabled debugging whilst connected and allowed debugging and now everything works fine.

Thanks for all the proposed solutions